# Python: Can I send messages and files over same socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I'm building a chat. The chat works great. But I'd like to add file send functionality to it. Which also works fine. Except I cannot break out of my file send loop once it starts writing to file, it just continually writes to file.

How can I chat, chat, chat, send a file, and then go back to chatting? Do I need to open up a second socket so I can close it?

The weird behavior - is that once the file has been sent, if I keep typing messages, they don't go to my "print to chat" methods that they usually go to, instead the messages continue to the "write to file" while loop that was started when the send file command started, and the other recipient receives no further messages.

Is it a good idea to try create a second socket connection when sendfile() is initiated, so that I can close it? How would I get the recipient to create a new socket too?

```
import os
import socket

    def xfer_file(self, path='image.jpg', client_socket):
        # This is fine. It's just going to start pouring in the data. 
        with open(path, 'rb') as f:
            filesize = os.path.getsize(path)
            # client_socket.send(f'filesize is: {filesize}'.encode())
            # From here, data just starts pouring into recipient file. 
            client_socket.sendfile(f, 0, filesize)

        client_socket.send(b'00000000000000000000000000') # for debug


    def receive_file(self, data, BUFFSIZE, client):
        # Begin to overwrite
        data = client.recv(BUFFSIZE)
        print(data) # for debug
        # I do this so the first chunk of data starts a new file
        with open('newfile','wb') as f:
            f.write(data) 
        
        while data:
            print(data) # for debug
            data = client.recv(BUFFSIZE)
            # The rest of the data chunks however, append to file. 
            with open('image(2).jpg', 'ab') as f:
                f.write(data)

        # I NEVER GET TO THIS POINT EVER. I DON'T KNOW HOW. 
        print("FINISHED==========")
        # And I don't want to close the socket, because I want
        # chat to continue after file transfer. 
        # sock.close()
```

Here is the chat if you want to see the limitations. It is a terminal chat for linux/osx (untested on windows).
https://github.com/sachio222/socketchat_v1

Comment: You need to define some way for the `receive_file()` function to know where the end of the file is, so that it will start reading messages again.

Comment: Your code keeps reading until the socket is closed. Obviously you can't use the same socket if the end of file is signalled by closing the socket.

Comment: One possibility is to send the file size first. `receive_file` reads the file size, then reads that many bytes from the socket. Then it returns to the main loop and starts processing messages again.

Comment: I thought of filesize, but I also feared it wouldn't always be accurate, and I'd end up in the same situation without any way of saving myself in case that I lost a byte or anything like that.

Comment: You could do it like HTTP. It has 3 options: Send filesize in the `Content-Length: header`, close the connection at the end of file, or use "chunked" encoding where you send a series of chunks of the file, each preceded by its length. The end of the file is signalled with chunk length = 0.

Comment: Or you could do it like SMTP. It indicates the end of the message by sending a line containing just `.`. If there are any lines in the message thare just `.`, it doubles it. The receiver has to convert any `..` lines back to `.`.

Comment: I think that the [zeromq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) is a great way of learning how to decompose communications into message passing entities that can interleave things like chat and files. You don't have to use zeromq (though it would be a good choice) to learn about the communications patterns it presents.